# How can I get a size of biggest file without open?

Tags: c++, windows, filesize

I know that there is `<sys/stat.h>` header but:

```
struct stat 
{
  dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
  ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
  mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
  nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
  uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
  gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
  dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
  off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
  blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
  blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of blocks allocated */
  time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
  time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
  time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

and max value of `off_t` is `2147483647` (on my machine) and that's less than 2GB.

Are there an other ways?

My OS is Win32.

Comment: Which OS? You have a system api to ask for file size. There is no need to open it.

Comment: Some systems offer a [stat64](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is a stat64 function that is POSIX compliant, it is not available on Windows (as mentioned in another answer, there is a _stat64 function though).

The most appropriate function to use in Windows is [GetFileAttributesEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example:

```
BOOL result;
WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fad;
LONGLONG filesize;

result = GetFileAttributesEx(filename, GetFileExInfoStandard, &fad);
if (result) {
    filesize = ((LONGLONG)fad.nFileSizeHigh << 32) + fad.nFileSizeLow;
}
```

Comment: LONGLONG is an "unsigned long long" ?

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230344.aspx for the exact definition. You can use `long long` or `__int64` too. Microsoft does not seem to provide unsigned 64-bit integer types.

Answer (score 3):

For file manipulation on Windows, you have two options.

- Find the appropriate standard or semi-standard C or POSIX function - in this case, [_stat64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx). This is more useful if you're trying to write more portable code, but even then, there are often incompatibilities with other platforms. (For example, Linux doesn't have a `_stat64`; instead, it uses a `#define` to make `stat` 64-bit capable.)
- Use the appropriate Windows API function - in this case, [GetFileAttributesEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For pure Windows apps, this may be easier and may expose more features than trying to use the standard or semi-standard C and POSIX functions.

Comment: If the questioner is not interested in all file information GetFileSizeEx might be sufficient.

Comment: @WernerHenze that function's first parameter is a HANDLE which implies opening the file beforehand. OP asks for a way to obtain file size without opening it.